# Changing mapping (url) for Spring MVC from java class (not from controller)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to change the url from Java class that is not a controller?

I've written a game of Go working as Client and Server applications (both written in Java, using Sockets to connect and exchange information in the shape of serialized messages). I run Server, two Clients, they connect and you can play. The client runs one javafx thread and one connecting thread that sends and listens for messages from Server as shown below. The server runs two threads that listen for messages from clients (decides turns internally), so you can surrender at any given time during the game. If it's not your turn moves and passes are ignored.

```
private void processCommands() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
            while (inputStream != null) {
                if(!keepRunning) {
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }
                ServerMessage serverMessage;
                serverMessage = (ServerMessage) this.inputStream.readObject();
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getServerMessage(serverMessage);
                        }
                    });
                if(serverMessage instanceof EndGame)
                    keepRunning = false;
            }

        }
```

Now, with javafx I just call Platform.runLater and javafx thread receives a message and acts according to it (for example, for Move it puts a piece of white or black color on the board).

I want to try to change Client into webapp and I decided to use SpringMVC(used it before). Can I change view or url from the client connection class? Or is there a better way to do this? Or maybe send message to controller somehow?